# how to import pd.dataframe list to the end of an existing excel file without overwriting it

Tags: python, excel, selenium

`import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd`

(imports list of exciting followers from excel:)

`prev_user_list = pd.read_csv('Final_users_followers_list.csv', delimiter=',').iloc[:,1:2] # useful to build a user log
prev_user_list = list(prev_user_list['0'])`

(My program then keeps track of any new followers it gains and ads them to the list of followers from 'Final_users_followers_list.csv' and spits out new combined excel file with both old and new followers:)

```
for n in range(0,len(new_followed)):
    prev_user_list.append(new_followed[n])

updated_user_df = pd.DataFrame(prev_user_list)
updated_user_df.to_csv('{}_users_followed_list.csv'.format(strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")))
```

How do I get python to just add new followers to the end of whats listed in 'Final_users_followers_list.csv'
and save ?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered your question, I'll take a shot at it.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\your_path\\test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['E','F','G','H'],
                   'Age': [100,70,40,60]})

reader = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\your_path\\test.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\your_path\\test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```